# How do they find positive neighborhood of set Frontier in BFS?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to understand the Breadth First Search complexity (work and span).
For the case in the picture, I don't understand how line 9 works, and from that to calculate the Work & Span.
[Full BFS using set X and F as boolean sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHWOy.png)

X is set of visited vertices, F is frontier set (i.e. is the positive neighbor vertices because this is directed graph, not undirected, positive mean you can move from A -> B, but not B -> A).

Anyone explain how line 9 works ? I tried but got a different result with the W,S in the lecture note from professor.
My question is how the N+G(F) work ?

For example: I have this graph, we are given 0 are the starting node.

[image]

The adjacent matrix:

```
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

For the first iterator:

```
X = 0,0,0,0
F = 1,0,0,0
```

How they calculate N+G(F) now ?
I tried but my way only lead to causing line 9 cost: W = |V|^2, S = 2.
But the result for the while BFS is W = |V|^2 ??? (my way could create |V|^3 ! )

So this is my method:
From the adjacent matrix. Each row I x with the boolean of that corresponding line in F -> each row result. Then I intersect these row results to have F'.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the sentence, "I tried but got the different with the W,S in the lecture note from professor," at all.  Can you please try to rephrase it?   As for your title, I don't understand what a "positive neighborhood" is.  In the algorithm, $N_G^+(F)$ appears to be the result of applying the "flatten" operation to F.  Finally, I changed the tag.  This has nothing to do with complex analysis, which is like calculus with complex numbers.

Comment: I think I understand now.  Although we don't see the definition of $N_G(F)$, I think it's $\{N_G(v)\mid v\in F\}$ where $N_G(v)$ is the set of vertices adjacent to $v$ in $G$.  Then $N_G^+(F)$ is the result of applying the flatten operation to $N_G(F)$ that is, taking the union of all the sets in $N_G(F)$.   Still, I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: @saulspatz I added more information. I think people familiar with BFS would clear understand this clearly and quickly. The problem is I don't have enough right to embedded image.

Comment: Also I don't understand his (my professor) flatten operation here. It's not stable so I'm trying to understand in more intuitively without understanding his flatten.